# Error creating apache certificate

Tags: apache, https, openssl, centos7

I have a CentOS server and I'm trying to install Apache Certificate using the following command:

`certbot --apache -d myDomain.com`

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for myDomain.com
Error while running apachectl graceful.

Job for httpd.service invalid.

Cleaning up challenges
Error while running apachectl graceful.

Job for httpd.service invalid.

Encountered exception during recovery
Error while running apachectl graceful.

Job for httpd.service invalid.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/error_handler.py", line 100, in _call_registered
    self.funcs[-1]()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 284, in _cleanup_challenges
    self.auth.cleanup(achalls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 1945, in cleanup
    self.restart()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 1834, in restart
    self._reload()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 1845, in _reload
    raise errors.MisconfigurationError(str(err))
MisconfigurationError: Error while running apachectl graceful.

Job for httpd.service invalid.

Error while running apachectl graceful.

Job for httpd.service invalid.
```

I check if Apache was running:

```
ps aux|grep httpd
root     16569  0.0  0.0   9064   920 pts/1    S+   14:44   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

I had no instances of apache running.

Any of you knows how can I fix this error or if there is workaround this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

certbot is clearly trying to start/restart apache and that's failing. There could be many reasons for that, and I would start by looking for the apache error log and seeing what it has. (There can be more than one, so check the timestamps.)

It would also be interesting to know if apache can start at all. What happens with a plain old `apachectl start`?

Comment: I ran the following commands. `httpd -k stop` and `apachectl start` after that I ran certbot --apache -d myDomain.com but now I'm getting this error: `Failed authorization procedure. myDomain.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization ::` any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like the LE side cannot read your challenge. That could be the directory is wrong in the config file, the file is being blocked by some access rule, the location is redirecting from http to https, etc. Make sure you can get a file from the well-known directory with curl without redirects.

Comment: how can do that?.

Comment: There's a limit to how much detail I'm "teach a man to fish". Read the curl documentation (or use your favored curl substitute; wget could probably do it).